# error: pathspec 'Build commit' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: git, github

I am new to git and I am getting the error below:

```
-bash-4.2$ cat README.md
# demo-project

Hello World.

Adding another line to demonstrate change!

Added one more line 10 Aug -2018 4.46 PM
-bash-4.2$ git commit -ma "Sample commit"
error: pathspec 'Sample commit' did not match any file(s) known to git.
-bash-4.2$ ls
README.md
-bash-4.2$
```

What might be the reason for this error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-m` switch needs to be followed by the commit message, so when passing several switches to the command, m should be the last. `git commit -am "Sample commit"` works. Or just specify -a and -m "Sample commit" separately.